# Can I track Journey Builder Interaction Plans?

Tags: journeybuilder, marketing-cloud

I really like the Journey Builder [WDF format](https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/workflow-format/getting-started.html) but I'm trying to figure out how we can track the progress of a Contact in an Interaction Plan.

From the UI it appears you can only track whether your audience reached the pre-defined Goal and view the result (the percentage/amount of the population that reach the Goal). That's OK, but I want to know where the Contacts are **dropping off** in the interaction plan **before** they reach the goal (or don't reach the goal). That is, if the activities within a goal aren't optimized (perhaps the Trigger, Activities or the Wait Period are incorrect), then I want to find out where that "dropout" point is and potentially create a new version of the Interaction Plan to test this.

I see there is an `ActivityOutcomes` object in WDF, but I can't find a way of finding these outcomes though the API. I guess that I could create a Custom Activity to fire an event to a listening service, for example if put a Custom Activity on the end of a Decision Split 'no' branch (e.g. if a customer does not purchase), but I would like to figure out if there's a way to track a Contact progress through an Interaction Plan.

I note that there's a `searchTraceEvents` method in the [Interaction Service Discovery Document API](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/interaction/rest.html) that searches for trace events in ElasticSearch — is this what I need to use? If so, is there any documentation around this somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you refer to is mostly relevant when you "work" with Interactions, but not the Contacts who are travelling within those interactions.

The easiest way to keep track of the progress for the contact would be to extend your trigger data extension with additional boolean columns and using [Customer Update Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/#CustomerUpdateActivities) simply update the record to flag where in the journey your contact is. You can have as many updates as needed and one of those relevant for your use case would be to update the field right before you exit an interaction before reaching the goal.